# How to get phantomjs running for pull requests in travis ci?

Tags: intern

I cannot get intern client tests running for pull requests in travis ci using phantomjs. I can run phantom locally and I can even run the tests using saucelabs in travis ci when the env vars are secure - push against my own fork.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- [Error](https://travis-ci.org/walmartlabs/lazojs/builds/38072768)
- [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/jstrimpel/lazojs/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L37)
- [Intern Config](https://github.com/jstrimpel/lazojs/blob/master/test/unit/conf.client.phantomjs.js)

Answer (score 0):

Moving the selenium start up to the travis `before_script` property solved the problem.